# Tracking carousel events in a hero-banner using Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

this is my first question posted on Stack overflow. Hope someone can help me out here

So my question is I'm trying to track the carousel events on a hero banner using Google Tag Manager. The problem I'm running into is based on where users click on the event card, different values are returned. For example, if a user clicks on the event title, only the event title returns; if a user clicks on the event date within the event card, only the event date returns. But regardless, this is the same event card that users click on, so a consistent value should be returned to my Google Analytics, e.g. the event title.

I'm having troubles figure this out. Can someone help? See below the codes behind the event card

```
        <div class="hero-carousel-template">
            <div class="item carousel-item-container text-White theme-grad-black" onclick="eventClick('https://www.hollywoodparklife.com/', '_self')">
                <div class="carousel-item-container__image">
                    <div class="carousel-item-container__image__content">
                        <img src="/content/dam/hwp-experience/marketing/Hero%20carousal_Rams.jpg" alt="ssa"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item-container__carousel-details carousel-text-overlay-container theme-grad-black text-White">
                    <div class="carousel-text-overlay-container__date-section">
                        <div class="carousel-text-overlay-container__heading">
                            Rams test
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-text-overlay-container__footer">
                            <div class="date-section">
                                <div class="carousel-text-overlay-container__date-section__day">
                                    FRI
                                </div>


                                <span class="separator">•</span>
                                <div class="carousel-text-overlay-container__date-section__date">
                                    18 Feb
                                </div>

                                <span class="separator">•</span>
                                <div class="carousel-text-overlay-container__date-section__time">
                                    8:00 PM
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-text-overlay-container__date-section__cta">
                                Brief info
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Also, there are multiple carousel events within the same hero banner, they have exact the same format and structure except the different event title, event date, event day, etc...

Thanks a lot!!!!